# Change the WMI Date to DATE ONLY

Tags: powershell, wmi

I have the PS line that determines the date and time of the last reboot of a server. This works as intended, but because some of our servers are in US Locale, I wish to change the format such that it is in "MMM dd yyyy". I actually do not need the time so this will be handy.

```
$Lastrebootime = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -Computername $Computer |
                 select csname, @{LABEL='LastBootUpTime';EXPRESSION={
                   $_.ConvertToDateTime($_.lastbootuptime)
                 }} -ErrorAction Stop
```

There doesn't seem to be a `ConvertToDate` only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `DateTime` object has a property `Date` which contains only the date portion:

```
$_.ConverttoDateTime($_.lastbootuptime).Date
```

Otherwise if you want a specific format anyway, just format the date:

```
$_.ConverttoDateTime($_.lastbootuptime).ToString('MMM dd yyyy')
```

This doesn't care about the time portion because it doesn't even appear in the format string.

Comment: Second one I prefer! Thanks